# Finding the singularities of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I need to find and classify the singularities of the function: $   f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}
{z^4-2}$. I'm aware that I'm going to have to first find the Laurent series corresponding to this function. I have tried using partial fractions but haven't come to an answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Skip the Laurent series on this one. All you will need is to find points $a$ such that the function doesn't have a limit as $z\to a$ and verify that multiplying the function by $(z-a)^n$, for some $n$, makes the limit finite. For this type of function, such an $n$ will always exist; all singularities of rational functions are poles. For example, take $a=2^{1/4}$ and $n=1$.

Comment: Ok I think I follow, so all I need to find are the points a, and these are my singularities?

Comment: Yes, the zeros of $z^4-2$ that don't get completely cancelled by those of $z^2+1$ (none of them do in this case).

Comment: I'm still a little iffy on this, can you give some more detail? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function has $4$ singularities, which are located at the $4$ fourth roots of $2$. Since the numerator doesn't vanish at any of them, $f$ has a simple pole at each one of them.